# How to find leap year leap year useing python

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, input, integer

hello my name is chetan I am trying the python code of leap year and nonleap year
can you give me a code for this program

I want to try how to check leap year and nonleap year using python but my code was incorrect.

Comment: Could you share some code that you tried?

Answer (score 0):

y=int(input("enter your year : "))

if (y % 400 == 0) or (y % 4 == 0 and y % 100 != 0) :
print("It is a leap year")
else :
print("It is not a leap year")

Comment: Format using ctrl + k